# Clarification: non-relativistic fine structure of a one-electron atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

The fine structure energy shift (in the non-relativistic limit) for a single-electron atom due to spin-orbit coupling is given by
$$\Delta E_l\propto\frac{j(j+1)-l(l+1)-s(s+1)}{2l(l+\frac{1}{2})(l+1)}$$
which does not apply when $l=0$ (as it would be singular). $l$ is the orbital angular momentum of the electron, $s$ is its spin angular momentum, and $j$ is the total angular momentum given by $|l-s|\le j\le l+s$ in integer steps $(\mathbf{j=l+s})$.

For the example of hydrogen in the $n=2$ level:

Am I right in thinking there is not supposed to be any shift for the $l=0$ s-orbital ($j=\frac{1}{2}$)? We can't calculate anything using the formula above in this case, but for the $l=1$ p-orbital, we get $\Delta E_l\propto -\frac{1}{3}$ for $j=\frac{1}{2}$. So there is a shift for the p-orbital with $j=\frac{1}{2}$, but seeing as fine structure splitting is supposed to depend on the value of $j$ not $l$, surely the s-orbital should be shifted $\propto -\frac{1}{3}$ as well (so the two $j=\frac{1}{2}$ energies are the same)?

Basically, what is correct and what is incorrect in the previous paragraph? Note: I am not considering relativistic effects, Lamb shift or Darwin shift as these are beyond the syllabus of my course